# Абсолютный путь и обычный

Tags: java, io

```
 System.out.println("Путь файла: " + file.getPath());
 System.out.println("Абсолютный путь файла " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

**Прочитал вот это**: 
Полный или абсолютный путь — это путь, который указывает на одно и то же место в файловой системе, вне зависимости от текущего рабочего каталога или других обстоятельств. Всё равно не очень понял, можете разъяснить?
В IDE один и тот же вариант в консоле

Comment: [Тут разбирали этот случай](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099300/whats-the-difference-between-getpath-getabsolutepath-and-getcanonicalpath)

Comment: Абсолютный путь, будет всегда указывать на одно и то же место в системе. Это значит, что, примеру, если вы зададите путь "C:\\temp\\dir1\\file1.dat" то это абсолютный путь. Независимо от того, на каком логическом диске будет лежать ваша программа (к примеру на лог.диск E), программа будет искать файл file1.dat строго по пути C:\\temp\\dir1\\.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вы не скажете, как пройти в библиотеку?**

***Абсолютный путь:*** 119019, Москва, ул. Воздвиженка, 3/5.

***Относительный путь:*** отсюда по улице 200 метров прямо, на перекрестке налево, 500 метров по проспекту, там стоит большой дом, это и есть библиотека.

Точка отсчета в абсолютном пути - самое начало: имя диска в Windows (например, `c:\`), корень файловой системы в линуксе `/`, доменное имя у веб-сайта (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) и всегда указывает на одно и то же место, неважно, откуда им пользоваться.

Точка отсчета в относительном пути - текущее расположение. Один и тот же относительный путь из разных мест будет указывать на разные файлы (см. пример как пройти в библиотеку). Описание пути с соседней улицы будет отличаться от описания пути из другого района.

Открыть файл по пути `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\change.log` можно из любого места. Открыть этот же файл по пути `Notepad++\change.log` можно только из папки `C:\Program Files`. Если обратиться по этому адресу из домашней папки пользвателя, то там наверняка ничего не окажется. Так же как и если пройти 200 метров по улице и 500 по проспекту с любого случайно взятого места, до Российской государственной библиотеки вряд ли дойдешь.

Comment: Искаю и читаю информацию уже порядка 30-40 минут и не нашел такого четкого примера, спасибо!

Comment: Получается это относительный путь: file.getPath(), да?

Comment: Нет, ``getPath()`` это путь с которым был создан объект File. Может быть и абсолютным и относительным, в зависимости от того, что использовалось при создании объекта.